# How to convert iOS local URI to path?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to get a base64 string from an image on the camera roll using react-native-fs and readFile returns 
`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'ph://`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very easy... Use copyAssetsFileIOS() from react-native-fs

Comment: Thanks, I'll research it

Comment: thanks for the pointer, I resolved my issue by creating a temporary copy of the file.

Comment: Yup. It's much easier with Android btw.